# Range Input won't reflect default value in Template Driven Form (Angular 2)

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms

I want my range inputs to load with a default value of 0.  When the page loads each input is set to the middle by default.  When I inspect the element I see this

```
<input
    class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"
    step="1"
    type="range"
    ng-reflect-model=""
    name="my_own_job"
    id="bus_info_04_a_01_01"
    min="0"
    max="10"
    value="0"
>
```

All the way at the end you see the value is indeed passed in.  Here's what the input looks like which is inside of an `*ngFor` by the way.

```
<input class="form-control" type="range" step="1"
    [attr.name]="ans.ctrlName"
    [attr.id]="ans.id"
    [attr.min]="Data.loExtreme"
    [attr.max]="Data.hiExtreme"
    [attr.value]="ans.value"
    [(ngModel)]="UserResponse[ans.respName]"
    #{{ans.respName}}="ngModel"
>
```

I'm also creating my variables dynamically like this

```
//From parent component
@Input() Data : Question;

//For dynamic variables for ngModel
UserResponse : { [ propName : string ] : string } = {};

//Function called in OnInit
loadResponses(){

     let data       : any           = this.Data;
     let control    : string        = data.ctrlName;
     let response   : string        = data.respName;
     let multiResp  : Array<any>    = data.answers;
     let defVal     : string        = '';
     let load       : Array<string> = [];

     load.push( control );

     if( response == '' || response == undefined ){

         if( this.Template == 'multi_fader' ){

             multiResp.forEach( resp => {

                 this.UserResponse[ resp.ctrlName ] = resp.answer;
                 this.UserResponse[ resp.respName ] = 0;

             });

         }
         else {

             multiResp.forEach( resp => {

                 this.UserResponse[ resp.ctrlName ] = resp.answer;
                 this.UserResponse[ resp.respName ] = defVal;

            });
        }
     }
     else {

         load.push(response);
         load.forEach( ctrl => { this.UserResponse[ ctrl ] = defVal; });

         this.UserResponse[ this.Data.ctrlName ] = this.Data.question;

    }
}
```

I tried setting the value to `UserResponse[respName]` but the `value` property on the input just shows up as the word `value` with no equal next to it.  I back and forth taking out the `value` property all together leaving just the `ngModel` stuff as well as commenting out the part of the function that sets the default value to see if just the `value` property alone would work without any other interference from from the function and it was the same result with the value being passed but the inputs being set in the middle.  I tried setting it to `1` just to see if maybe `0` was making it `null` but that made no difference.

I even changed the `value` property on each question for that input in my `json` file to `1` and it shows up in the inspection yet doesn't change the default placement of the input.  Can someone please shed some light on why this is happening and how to fix it?  Here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nBpriDOgC88Fo2WMpM6A?p=preview) of the entire mechanism if you need to see what else is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change in the template,

```
[attr.value]="ans.value"
```

to,

```
[(ngModel)]="ans.value"
```

it should initialize the value to zero in the range input view (confirmed in plunker). Not sure what you are doing with the other `ngModel` in your template though.

Comment: As I said in the answer, all I did was change the `[attr.value]` to `[(ngModel)]` on line #257 of 'question-shell.component.html', thats all. Even with the other `[(ngModel)]="UserResponse[ans.respName]"` (on line #258) present in template. You might likely have to change that based on your logic.

Comment: yeah I just swapped it around and seen that did register.  The other ngModel you're talking about was my attempt to provide `ans.value` through the value of a dynamic variable I created to bind to the inputs.  so this really has me puzzled because `UserResponse[resp.name]` provides the same value as `ans.value` because I'm loading it in the function.

Comment: I don't think so they both refer to the same value! See in questions.json you have value = 0 whereas resp.name = <some_string_value>. See for example, in one element of answers list: { "answer" : "A way of creating my own job doing what I love.", "id" : "bus_info_04_a_01_01", "value" : "0", "ctrlName" : "my_own_job", "respName" : "my_own_job_resp" }

Comment: Then inside your `loadResponses()` you are assigning `this.UserResponse[ resp.respName ] = defVal;`, but `defVal` is initialized to `''` (empty string) instead of `0`. Hope I read that code right :)

Comment: the part that effects that in the function is in the part where it says `if template == 'multi_fader` towards the top.  I've gone back and forth from setting it directly to 0 or using `resp.value` which goes to the same value as `ans.value` in the template.

Comment: This indeed works and I'm thrilled to know it does..... but it also showed me I'm trying to rig everything up wrong and need to look more into the different uses of `[(ngModel)]` vs `#something="ngModel"` vs just `ngModel`.  I'm seeing so many examples that breeze over them that I'm really not sure of which is more appropriate in which circumstances and why.  Thanks for your help with the issue.